# Selenium Automation Upload file issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, file-upload, automation, automated-tests, absolute-path

While debugging I found out that my tests fail because of the unloaded file.

I tried many different locators and checked the absolute path to uploading file, but it just doesn't want to upload the file!

It would be great if you will check this form:
http://tutorialsninja.com/demo/index.php?route=product/product&path=25_28&product_id=42

Code parts related to issue:

```
  String path = "C:\\Users\\username\\IdeaProjects\\selenium_bootcamp\\src\\resources\\image.jpg";

  @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//button[@id='button-upload222']")
public WebElement fileInputApplePage;

 public void uploadFileOnApplePage() {
    fileInputApplePage.sendKeys(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of your input field which you need to upload file is hidden, and you should change it to file, for continuing the upload process

```
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('input-option222').setAttribute('type', 'file')");

 WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("input-option222"));

 input.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\rober\\IdeaProjects\\selenium_bootcamp\\src\\resources\\image.jpg");
```

**UPDATE:
Upload with Robot framework**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button-upload222")).click();

  
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\rober\\IdeaProjects\\selenium_bootcamp\\src\\resources\\image.jpg");

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks to you the file is now chosen, but actually not uploaded. Something missing.

Comment: I think in this case you can use upload with Robot framework, I have updated my answer